# Getting ID of a firestore document using a conditional query in Node,js using then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I have been try to fetch a firestore document ID using a condition. Something like, if a document has its secret_code field "ABCD12", fetch that document's id. I have been trying to do this with Node.js but it does not seem to be working. The code returns {Promise}

I think I have not understood then() well enough.

`

```
async function getIdFromSecretCode(secret_code) {
  doc_id=0
  await userCollection
    .where("secret_code", "==", secret_code)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

        doc_id = doc.id;
        // console.log(doc_id);
        //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      });
    });
  return doc_id;
}
var t= getIdFromSecretCode("ABCD")
console.log(t)
```

`

The o/p is:
`

```
PS E:\socketio-unity-main> node mserver.js
Promise { <pending> }
```

`
I want it to return the document id like "1xccecefgrf"

Answer (score 1):

`getIdFromSecretCode` is an `async` function so it will *always* return a promise. You cannot expect a future result to be available now, so you'll need to embrace promises, also in the main call to `getIdFromSecretCode`.

Moreover, that promise is currently not resolving to anything useful, so you have to adapt that code a bit:

```
async function getIdFromSecretCode(secret_code) {
    const snapshot = await userCollection
        .where("secret_code", "==", secret_code)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs[0]?.doc_id;
}

getIdFromSecretCode("ABCD").then(t => {
    console.log(t);
});
```